# trying to display message from db using id from url on same page. message details only flash on screen for a second

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

url only updates when pressed button is pressed once and has to be pressed again to show details. The reason I can press it twice is because the div='read' flashes blank the first time and with the details the second time.
Don't know how to fix the div from flashing and how to set url before it opens to div with the results.

***PHP AT THE TOP OF ACCOUNT PAGE***

```
$getmessages = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE messages.receiver='$email' ORDER BY date DESC";
$messageresult = mysqli_query($conn, $getmessages) or die(mysqli_error($conn));



if (isset($_GET['msgid'])) {
    $filter = $_GET["msgid"];

    $getmessage = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE messages.message_id ='$filter'";
    $getresult = mysqli_query($conn, $getmessage) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

if (mysqli_num_rows($getresult) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getresult)) {
        $displaysub = $row["subject"];
        $displaydate = $row["date"];
        $displaysender = $row["sender"];
        $displayreceiver = $row["receiver"];
        $displaymessageid = $row["message_id"];
        $displaymessage = $row["message"];
    }
}
} else {
    $displaysub = "";
        $displaydate = "";
        $displaysender = "";
        $displayreceiver = "";
        $displaymessageid = "";
        $displaymessage = "";
}



mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

**MAIN HTML/PHP**

```
<div id="msginbox">
                            <h4><strong>Inbox</strong></h4>
                            <table id="inbox" class="table table-bordered table-responsive ">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Date</th>
                                        <th>Sender</th>
                                        <th>Subject</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php
                                    if (mysqli_num_rows($messageresult) > 0) {
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($messageresult)) {
                                            $sub = $row["subject"];
                                            $rdate = $row["date"];
                                            $sender = $row["sender"];
                                            $messageid = $row["message_id"];
                                            $message = $row["message"];

                                            echo "<tr>";
                                            echo "<td id='left'><p>" . $rdate . "</p></td>";
                                            echo "<td id='left'><p>" . $sender . "</p></td>";
                                            echo "<td id='left'><p>" . $sub . "</p></td>";

                                            echo "<td>" . "<button value='account.php?msgid=$messageid' class='btn btn-primary replyback'>Reply</button>" . "</td>";
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ?>     
                                </tbody>
                            </table>



                        </div>
                        <div id="read">
                                <p><strong>From: </strong><?php echo $displaysender; ?><br></p>
                                <br>
                                <p><strong>Date: </strong><?php echo $displaydate; ?><br></p>
                                <br>
                                <p><strong>Subject: </strong><?php echo $displaysub; ?><br></p>
                                <br>
                                <p><strong>Message: </strong><?php echo $displaymessage; ?></p>
                                <br>
                                <button id="back">Back</button>

                            </div>
```

***JQUERY***

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.replyback').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#read').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#msginbox').css('display', 'none');
                     var newurl = $(this).attr("value");
                     window.location.href = newurl;


                });
 });
```

Comment: Why not disable the button in the on click event to prevent clicking a 2nd time?

Comment: the issue is that the first click will only set the url after the div='read' opens and then it displays no information because the query is using a _GET to run the query

Comment: So disable the button, and change it's label to "Loading" until the AJAX returns.

Comment: Still doesn't stop the div from flashing on screen and disappearing

Comment: Put the section starting with $('#msginbox' before the line starting with $('#read'). IOW, hide the container before you show the contents.